# How to edit FTP URLs to HTTP to make images display?

Tags: image, http, ftp

I need to upload images into a page in my website.

I usually use WinSCP FTP program because it gives me the option "Copy to Clipboard (Include paths)". I copy images' URL through this option and the images are usually uploading and displaying successfully to the website.

I'm trying to do the same now for a new page but that is not working. Using any option in WinSCP is not helping at all. All I get is a small icon instead of the image. But when I use FileZilla for copying the URL, the images are uploading and displaying successfully. BUT the problem is that the page is requesting the username and the password to display the images.

I've been googling about it and I realise that the problem could be that I need to change the FTP URL to HTTP. I tried to do it this way:

```
ftp://username@domain.org/domain_restore/pics/anton.jpg
```

to:

```
http://username.domain.org/anton.jpg
```

That is probably totally wrong? I tried some other ways but the problem is I'm only a beginner and I don't have the knowledge how to edit it or how to find out what the problem is.

I followed the instructions of someone from the support of my host and they advised me to do a restore to all my directories in the FTP manager. I did that but I feel like I messed it up because now all the folders and the directories are duplicated. Could that also be the problem?